# How do I delete a foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy, mysql-error-1025

I'm using SQLAlchemy Migrate to keep track of database changes and I'm running into an issue with removing a foreign key.  I have two tables, t_new is a new table, and t_exists is an existing table.  I need to add t_new, then add a foreign key to t_exists.  Then I need to be able to reverse the operation (which is where I'm having trouble).

```
t_new = sa.Table("new", meta.metadata,
    sa.Column("new_id", sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True)
)
t_exists = sa.Table("exists", meta.metadata,
    sa.Column("exists_id", sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column(
        "new_id", 
        sa.types.Integer,
        sa.ForeignKey("new.new_id", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False
    )
)
```

This works fine:

```
t_new.create()
t_exists.c.new_id.create()
```

But this does not:

```
t_exists.c.new_id.drop()
t_new.drop()
```

Trying to drop the foreign key column gives an error: 1025, "Error on rename of '.\my_db_name\#sql-1b0_2e6' to '.\my_db_name\exists' (errno: 150)"

If I do this with raw SQL, i can remove the foreign key manually then remove the column, but I haven't been able to figure out how to remove the foreign key with SQLAlchemy?  How can I remove the foreign key, and then the column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with sqlalchemy.migrate.

In order to make it work, I have had to create the foreign key constraint explicitly rather than implicitely with Column('fk', ForeignKey('fk_table.field')):

Alas, instead of doing this:

```
p2 = Table('tablename',
            metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('fk', ForeignKey('fk_table.field')),
            mysql_engine='InnoDB',
           )
```

do that:

```
p2 = Table('tablename',
            metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('fk', Integer, index=True),
            mysql_engine='InnoDB',
            )
ForeignKeyConstraint(columns=[p2.c.fk], refcolumns=[p3.c.id]).create()
```

Then the deletion process looks like this:

```
def downgrade(migrate_engine):
     # First drop the constraint
     ForeignKeyConstraint(columns=[p2.c.fk], refcolumns=[p3.c.id]).drop()
     # Then drop the table
     p2.drop()
```

Comment: For anyone who may run into this - ForeignKeyConstraint needs to be imported from `migrate` not from `sqlalchemy`.

Comment: I don't know in what version of sqlalchemy de `drop` method was removed, but i managed to achieve the same using `op.drop_constraint(_FK_NAME, _TABLE_NAME, type_="foreignkey")`, and creating by using: `op.create_foreign_key(_FK_NAME, _TABLE_NAME, "dest_table", ["src_column"], ["dest_column"])`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a separate metadata instance and using Session.execute() to run raw SQL.  Ideally, there would be a solution that uses sqlalchemy exclusively, so I wouldn't have to use MySQL-specific solutions.  But as of now, I am not aware of such a solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the SQL you executed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with SQLAlchemy-Migrate.  Note that a ForeignKey is on an isolated column.  A ForeignKeyConstraint is at the table level and relates the columns together.  If you look at the ForeignKey object on the column you will see that it references a ForeignKeyConstraint.

I would unable to test this idea because of the two databases I use MS SQL isn't supported by SqlAlchemy-Migrate and sqlite doesn't support "alter table" for constraints.  I did get SQLAlchemy to try to remove a FK via a drop on the references constraint on a sqlite table so it was looking good.  YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can achieve this in sqlalchemy: just `drop()` the all the constraints before you `drop()` the column (theoretically, you might have multiple constraints):

```
def drop_column(column):
    for fk in column.table.foreign_keys:
        if fk.column == column:
            print 'deleting fk ', fk
            fk.drop()
    column.drop()

drop_column(t_exists.c.new_id)
```

Comment: I tried this out, but got an error: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'drop'.  I checked out the docs but didn't see any way to do this: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/schema.html?highlight=foreignkey#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey

Comment: this is fair, but show me the documentation of SA where Column has drop(): http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/schema.html?highlight=foreignkey#sqlalchemy.schema.Column

Comment: 'SQLAlchemy-Migrate' adds drop(), create() and other niceties but it needs to be installed separately. See http://packages.python.org/sqlalchemy-migrate/index.html

Comment: SQLAlchemy-Migrate adds drop() and create() to ForeignKeyConstraint not ForeignKey.